# Is the limit unique in the maximum norm on $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $v=(x,y) \in R^2$  we define the norm of $v$ by

$|| v ||=\max(|x|,|y|)$

Now suppose that we have a sequence $v_n$ that converge to $v=(3,1)$. Does this sequence does not converge to $v=(3,2)$ also?

Comment: no, why would it?

Comment: can you check the definition of your norm again? as of now, it can be negative

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh you are right . I will edit my question

Comment: Both points have norm $3$, but that doesn't make them equal; is that the issue...?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang yes that the issue.

Comment: Not sure if the last comment means the question is answered, but in case not: The (max-)distance between $(3, 2)$ and $(3, 1)$ is not zero. (Analogously, there exist distinct points on the Euclidean circle of radius $3$ about the origin. :)